# Using pthreads I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" only in big values

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

This is a program to make the (square) sum of an array using threads. It works fine if the array elements are up to about 2.000.000 but after that I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Could it be because I am using ubuntu in a virtual machine and I have allocated 4GB of RAM in it?

Thank you for your time!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int part = 0;
int local_elements = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* square_sum(void* arg);

int main()
{
    int threads, total_elements;
    int i;
    void *loc_sum = NULL;
    long long total_sum = 0;


    printf("Give the number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d", &threads);


    /*-----Fixed big size array-----*/
    total_elements = 2000000; // <--- If this value gets big I get that error
    local_elements = total_elements/threads;
    int element_array[total_elements];

    for (int i=0; i<total_elements; i++) {
        //Filling all the positions with 1s
        element_array[i] = 1;
    }

    //Creating the threads
    pthread_t newthread[threads];
    for (int i=0; i<threads; i++) {
        //The thread function gets the element array
        pthread_create(&newthread[i], NULL, square_sum, (void *)element_array);
    }


    //Waiting for each thread to finish and creating the total_sum
    for (int i=0; i<threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(newthread[i], (void*) &loc_sum);
        printf("Thread %d returned the local_sum: %d \n", i, (int)loc_sum);
        total_sum += (int)loc_sum;  
    }

    printf("\nThe total square sum of the array is: %lld\n", total_sum);

    return 0;
}


void* square_sum(void* arg) {

    intptr_t local_sum = 0;



    int *element_array = (int *) arg;

    //--- Start of critical section ---
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    //Each thread computes its part
    int thread_part = part++;

    for (int i = thread_part*local_elements; i < (thread_part+1)*local_elements; i++) {
        local_sum += element_array[i] * element_array[i];
        //printf("Thread %d says -- element %d is: %d \n", thread_part, i, element_array[i]);

    }


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //--- End of critical section ---


    return ((void*)local_sum);


}
```

Comment: Just a note, you need locking around shared data, such as part. Otherwise, you have a race, and UB.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Thank you for the recommendation. More specifically, where else should I place mutex locking other than where I already have? I am new in this and I don't fully understand it yet!

Comment: Sorry, I read the code too quickly. Compiling and checking it now, but someone else may beat me to the conclusion :)

Comment: It is too much for stack if it allocated on stack.

Answer (score 1):

Kiran Biradar is correct. I get correct results with ulimit -s 80000 (I ran as root to set high ulimit) for this hacked version of your program. Alternatively, allocating the array on the heap or as static should also avoid the stack size problem, as mentioned by another commenter.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int part = 0;
int local_elements = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* square_sum(void* arg) {

    int* local_sum = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));



    int *element_array = (int *) arg;

    //--- Start of critical section ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    //Each thread computes its part                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    int thread_part = part++;

    for (int i = thread_part*local_elements; i <
             (thread_part+1)*local_elements; i++) {
        *local_sum += element_array[i] * element_array[i];
        //printf("Thread %d says -- element %d is: %d \n", thread_part, i,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        //element_array[i]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
//--- End of critical section ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          


    return local_sum;

}


int main()
{
    int threads, total_elements;
    int i;
    int* loc_sum;
    long long total_sum = 0;


    printf("Give the number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d", &threads);


    /*-----Fixed big size array-----*/
    total_elements = 2000000; // <--- If this value gets big I get that error                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    local_elements = total_elements/threads;
    int element_array[total_elements];

    for (int i=0; i<total_elements; i++) {
        //Filling all the positions with 1s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        element_array[i] = 1;
    }

    //Creating the threads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    pthread_t newthread[threads];
    for (int i=0; i<threads; i++) {
        //The thread function gets the element array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        pthread_create(&newthread[i], NULL, square_sum, element_array);
    }


    //Waiting for each thread to finish and creating the total_sum                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for (int i=0; i<threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(newthread[i], (void**)&loc_sum);
        printf("Thread %d returned the local_sum: %d \n", i, *loc_sum);
        total_sum += *(int*)loc_sum;
        free(loc_sum);
        printf("loc_sum %d\n", *loc_sum);
    }

    printf("\nThe total square sum of the array is: %lld\n", total_sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
int element_array[total_elements];
```

is too big to be allocated in the in the stack. 2.000.000 positions requires 8Mb of memory, and Linux's default stack size is 8Mb, as can be seen by running `ulimit -s`. To fix it, you can use `malloc` to allocate it in the heap, or use the `static` keyword, as it will allocate the array in the `.data` segment, which usually has a 4Gb limit in `amd64` machines.

Comment: No. 2 million ints is typically 8 MB, you are off by a factor of a thousand.

Comment: Indeed. In this case the `static` keyword will fix his problem.